# How can I transform the list into the required form?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics

I have the list:

```
List1={{7, {-0.91, {a -> 0.61}}}, {10, {-1.41, {a ->
     0.44}}}, {12, {-2.00, {a ->
     0.35}}}, {15, {-2.69, {a -> 0.28}}}}
```

I would like to multiply the numbers -0.91, -1.41, -2.00, -2.69 by 5 and write them into the following list:

```
List2={{7, -0.91*5}, {10,-1.41*5}, {12, -2.00*5}, {15, -2.69*5}}
```

How can I do it without a lot of loops?

Comment: ``Transpose[{List1[[All, 1]], 5 List1[[All, 2, 1]]}]``

Answer (score 6):

All answers are fine and upvoted. I am leaving another approach here -which also seems the simplest so far in my eyes

```
List1 /. {i_, {j_, k_}} :> {i, 5*j}
```

> [image: list]

Comment: (+1) Hi, friend! For me, your answer is the best :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López hey mate. Thanks a lot! You make me blush :-)

Comment: Nitpick: If `List1` has length 2, then this does the wrong thing. `Replace[List1,{i_,{j_,_}}:>{i,5*j},{1}]` should work.

Comment: @user293787 yes, that's a good point. Thanks for bringing it up :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
{First[#], Times[Last[#], 5]} & /@ (Most[#] & /@ (Flatten[#, 2] & /@ list1))
```

Or using `Take`:

```
Take[{#[[1]], 5*#[[2]]}, {1, 2}] & /@ Flatten /@ list1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Transpose[MapAt[5*# &, Extract[List1, {{All, 1}, {All, 2, 1}}], 2]]
```

Or

```
SubsetMap[5*# &, Extract[#, {{1}, {2, 1}}] & /@ List1, {All, 2}]
```